# Shell. Открыть терминал на всех компьютерах linux

Tags: shell, linux

У меня *xubuntu* и, естественно, для того, что бы открыть из шела терминал, я пишу "xfce4-terminal". На *федоре* с *kde* пишу "xterm".

Но это всё эмуляторы с приятным оформлением. Как вызвать (если можно так сказать, кроссплатформенно) терминал, что бы на всех семействах открывался?

*Term*, *terminal* пробовал.

Comment: наверное xterm?

Comment: А кроме Иксов уже ничего и нету???

Comment: Люди даже о "браузерах по умолчанию" до сих пор не договорились, а вы про эмулятор терминала :)

Answer (score 2):

в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах можно пользоваться командой `x-terminal-emulator`.

в тех же системах, где её нет, можно, например, создать *symlink* такого вида:

```
$ sudo ln -s /полный/путь/к/программе-эмулятору /usr/local/bin/x-terminal-emulator
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего это делать через SSH (там канал шифрованный):

1. Надо установить SSH на обоих компах (обычно в пачке устанавливаются и клиент, и сервер, но если где-то что-то недо, то надо доустановить).
2. Затем, в обычной консоли даётся команда

> ssh "адрес куда хотите подцепиться"

(без кавычек, конечно)

Там вам будет выдан запрос логин/пароль. Если всё правильно, то вуаля!

Я так не то, что между Линухами, а и с вендов через PuTTY делаю!

А вот тут ещё больше инфы по SSH: http://mydebianblog.blogspot.ru/2006/12/ssh.html

Comment: Нет, Вы меня не поняли.Я говорю про этот терминал http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/-28062013-083500.phpКоторый именно в окружении каждый свой. Я его открываю из шелла. Но это не переносится между разными семействами Linux.

Comment: того что вы хотите в прямом смысле нет, все зависит от графического окружения, в которое входит эмулятор. Так что бы какой то из них был по дефолту везде , практически не возможно, лишь по тому что состав дистрибутива зависит от того кто его ставит.

Comment: @pyatak, преобразуйте в ответ. Это то, что я хотел услышать)

Answer (score 0):

Терминал который можно открыть на любых версиях *nix  это консоль:
 Ctrl+Alt+F2
(или 3-8) :)  универсально, но правда сворачивается графический интерфейс.

Вернуться Ctrl+Alt+F9 или Alt+F9

В графическом интерфейсе как верно заметил  pyatak по дефолту никак - состав и окружение зависит от дистрибутива.

Если все сервера принадлежат вам, никто не запрещает доставить удобную для вас консоль(эмулятор) на них и вызывать его по хоткею или линку(alias)